# RSQLite Error "hash is not an exported object"

Tags: r, sqlite

I am trying to scrape some pitchf/x data and store it in an SQLite database. However, I am receiving the following error when I run the following code:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
db <- src_sqlite("pitchfx.sqlite3", create = T)
```

This is the error:

```
    Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect': .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RSQLite', details:
  call: NULL
  error: 'hash' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang'
In addition: Warning message:
`src_sqlite()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.0.0.
Please use `tbl()` directly with a database connection
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
```

I have been unable to figure out how to fix this. I have reinstalled the package, updated Rlang, restarted R, nothing has worked. I'm on R 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical method (hinted in that error message) is to use a `DBI` connection directly:

```r
library(DBI)   # dbConnect, dbWriteTable
library(dplyr) # tbl
mycon <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "pitchfx.sqlite3", create = TRUE)
dbWriteTable(mycon, "mt", mtcars)
tbl(mycon, "mt")
# # Source:   table<mt> [?? x 11]
# # Database: sqlite 3.33.0 [c:\Users\r2\Projects\ADS\pitchfx.sqlite3]
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
# 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# # ... with more rows
```

and used something like

```r
tbl(mycon, "mt") %>%
  filter(cyl == 4L, disp > 120) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 5 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
# 2  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
# 3  21.5     4  120.    97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
# 4  26       4  120.    91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
# 5  21.4     4  121    109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2
```